# First-Order Logic: If $\mathcal{N}\models\phi$ for every $\mathcal{N}$, then $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{N}$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Given that the alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ is finite and that $\mathcal{M}$ is a finite $\mathcal{L}_A$ structure, prove that there is an $\mathcal{L}_A$-sentence $\phi$ such that for every $\mathcal{L}_A$-structure $\mathcal{N}$, if $\mathcal{N}\models\phi$, then $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be in class right now?

Comment: Let the elements of $M$ be $a_1$ to $a_t$. Write down the complet.e diagram of $M$. Now make a sentence that says there are $x_1$ to $x_t$,  all distinct, such that any $x$ is one of these, and now write down the conjunction of the sentences in the full diagram of $M$, with $a_i$ replaced by $x_i$.

Comment: I am 100% sure that this was asked in the past, but I can't seem to find a link.

Answer (score 0):

If the universe of $\mathcal{M}$ is finite then the interpretations of any constant, function or relation in the language is a finite object. Since there are finitely many of them, one can come up with a sentence with as many variables as there are elements in $\mathcal{M}$, then take the conjunction of the sentence that says that they are all unique and nothing else exists, in conjunction with formulas that spell out the interpretation of everything, element by element. Can you see how?